# How can I implement an instant notification behavior between user in Sprong Boot backend (using Angular frontend)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot project and I was wondering if it was possible to implement a behavior that in some way could be similar to Google Firebase database reaction when data change. The front end of this application in made in Angular

I try to better explain what I mean. At the moment my Spring Boot project is composed by a set of APIs. So the front end call a back end API and retrieve data, as simple as that.

Now I am starting to implement a new notification feature. It should work in the following way:

- An user create a notification. Basically it call a back end API (defined on my Spring Boot project) sending a note (a simple object containing some fields like **title**, **note**, **category**, **sourceUser**, **destinationUser**).

This note message must be automatically delivered to the **destionationUser** that have to immediatly obtain it as notification in its front end.

How can I implement a behavior like this?

Comment: Have a look at [Websockets](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html)

Answer (score 1):

You may should use websockets with push notifications.
Read more at below answer of the another similar question.
[Spring Boot - Push message to Angular UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56988161/spring-boot-push-message-to-angular-ui)